# [HOWLER.JS]pause for some second(s) between audio files / mp3 files in the src property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, howler.js

How do I pause for some seconds (e.g 10 seconds) between the audio file in the src property?

```
const sound = new Howl({
   src: ['a.mp3','b.mp3'],
});
sound.play();
```

I want to put a delay for the second song, in this case the `b.mp3` for 10 seconds. so when the `a.mp3` reaches its end, it pauses for 10 seconds, and play the `b.mp3` afterwards

Comment: Howl provide pause([id]) function. You can call it after ten seconds by the setTimeout.

Comment: could you elaborate the workaround, please?